# cv::imshow on two different threads, imshow hang after a while

Tags: c++, opencv, computer-vision, camera

My goal is to `cv::imshow("Live")` and `cv::imshow("ROI")` on two different threads.

The Live window is to display the frame captured by the Camera. The ROI window is to display the frame that will be used to focus.

The problem is after a while the `cv::imshow("Live")` and `cv::imshow("ROI")` hang up.

[image]

main.cpp

```
#include <opencv2/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/videoio.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include "JetsonCamera.hpp"
#include <thread>
#include<unistd.h>

using namespace std::chrono_literals;

void previewROI(cv::Mat& frame) {
    // Known issue due to X11 Forwarding
    // error snippet: [xcb] Unknown sequence number while processing reply
    // solution: delay by 1s before creating new window
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(1s);

    while (frame.empty()) {
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(1s);
    }

    cv::Rect roi(100, 100, 200, 200); // Define the region of interest
    
    cv::Mat roiFrame = frame(roi);
    cv::namedWindow("ROI", cv::WINDOW_NORMAL);
    for (;;) {
        cv::imshow("ROI", roiFrame);
        if (cv::waitKey(5) >= 0) break;
    }
}

int main(int, char**)
{
    cv::Mat frame;
    Camera cap;
    if (!cap.isOpened()) {
        std::cerr << "Failed to open camera\n";
        return 1;
    }

    std::thread previewThread(previewROI, std::ref(frame)); // Create a new thread to preview ROI
    
    cv::namedWindow("Live", cv::WINDOW_NORMAL);
    //--- GRAB AND WRITE LOOP
    std::cout << "Start grabbing" << std::endl
              << "Press any key to terminate" << std::endl;
    for (;;)
    {
        // wait for a new frame from camera and store it into 'frame'
        bool success = cap.getFrame(frame);
        // check if we succeeded
        if (frame.empty()) {
            std::cerr << "ERROR! blank frame grabbed\n";
            break;
        }
        // show live and wait for a key with timeout long enough to show images
        cv::imshow("Live", frame);
        if (cv::waitKey(5) >= 0) break;
    }
    previewThread.join(); // Wait for the preview thread to finish
    // the camera will be deinitialized automatically in VideoCapture destructor
    return 0;
}
```

JetsonCamera.cpp

```
#include "JetsonCamera.hpp"
#include <iostream>

Camera::Camera() : cap_(
        "nvarguscamerasrc sensor-id=0 ! "
        "video/x-raw(memory:NVMM),width=(int)4656,height=(int)3496,format=(string)NV12,framerate=(fraction)9/1 ! "
        "nvvidconv flip-method=0 ! "
        "video/x-raw,width=(int)1280,height=(int)1280,format=(string)BGRx ! "
        "videoconvert ! "
        "video/x-raw,format=(string)BGR ! "
        "appsink", 
        cv::CAP_GSTREAMER
    ) {}

bool Camera::isOpened() {
    return cap_.isOpened();
}

bool Camera::getFrame(cv::Mat& frame) {
    return cap_.read(frame);
}
```

JetsonCamera.hpp

```
#ifndef CAMERA_HPP
#define CAMERA_HPP

#include <opencv2/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/videoio.hpp>

class Camera {
    public:
        Camera();
        bool isOpened();
        bool getFrame(cv::Mat& frame);

    private:
        cv::VideoCapture cap_;
};

#endif /* CAMERA_HPP */
```

Comment: calling OpenCV GUI functions from multiple threads is illegal for several GUI backends used by OpenCV. please use a proper GUI toolkit. or make sure to call imshow from a single thread, by passing the data between threads.

Comment: Can you try to call cv::startWindowThread() once in your main thread before starting another thread?

Comment: @Micka the startWindowThread makes the entire app unresponsive.

Answer (score 0):

In my app I had to

- install GTK3 (seems that there is aproblem with GTK2)
- and call startWindowThread only when I'm not in the main thread.

E.g.

```
#if __has_include(<sys/types.h>) && __has_include(<unistd.h>)
#define START_WINDOW_THREAD
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#endif

....

#ifdef START_WINDOW_THREAD
    // Don't call startWindowThread in the main thread. GTK will
    // not return the key strokes in waitKey otherwise.
    if (getpid() != gettid())
    {
        std::cerr << "Not in main thread " << getpid() << " != " << gettid() << std::endl;
        cv::startWindowThread();
    }
#endif
// Create the window
cv::namedWindow(m_name, cv::WINDOW_NORMAL);
cv::resizeWindow(m_name, 640, 480);
```